# How to make a JS variable cross over HTML pages?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global-variables

I'm trying to make a simple login form for only two people, so I'm putting the login in the code and encrypting it. I want a variable to cross over two HTML pages. How do you do this? See [this](https://github.com/LukeStro47/Login-Test). Thanks!

Comment: Just declare `var uesername;` outside `check()` fn and you are good to go.

Comment: anyway, you can store it in a cookie